# ViewModel Do's and Don'ts

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, domain-driven-design

I am now at the fun part of my journey in building an MVC application. I have spent the last 3 weeks researching architecture, ONION specifically, and learning about IOC/DI and such.

So my question is this:
What is the best way to implement ViewModels? I have seen some terrible examples so far.

Comment: Terrible examples? Such as? Can you post them? Links to them?

Comment: Hahha. No! I am sure 5 minutes on google will do it for ya though. One that bothered me that I ran across was somebody sending the ViewModel to the ServiceLayer, grabbing the data from the ViewModel and then updating the database. So now the ServiceLayer has a dependency on that specific ViewModel... Did not sit well with me.

Comment: With regards to the service layer, that can be used in cases where they specifically cache view models for performance, see CQRS (beware your head may a-splode)

Comment: Cool, but at least inject an interface if you are going to go that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I recommend reviewing this article which outlines different 'tactics' for handling view models.**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

**Some recommendations I can give you for view models is:**

- Base them directly on your view & what the user interface needs,
- Prefer creating custom view models for seperate pages instead of generalizing them to be re-used across different views.
- Keep them simple & flat, don't go overboard with inheritance etc.
- If you are mapping from database models, adopt an existing method for mapping between your models and view models such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)
- Consider using [dynamic](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx) in some cases, its more flexible and can have less friction.

Comment: Awesome and thank you. I will add your answer to my list of "ViewModel" do's and don't for my blog.

Comment: @Code Oh sweet, comment the link if you don't mind once its up.  As flattered as I am that you accepted the answer I would wait a bit, there's probably lots of other feedback out there ; )